# How to show Custom Field Value in Woocommerce Shop Page

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, theme-customizer

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','fun',10);
function fun()
{

echo 'custom_field_value';

}
```

Note: I want to replace the title on shop page with custom field value. The code is correct but the echo part I need help on it.

Comment: try this code :if (is_shop()){
echo 'custom_field_value';
}

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` is not the right hook to change the title on shop page.

Try this instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', function() {
    echo 'custom_field_value';
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I need help on this section only since the code I have provided is 100% working to remove the title.

`echo 'custom_field_value';`

If I will call custom field as custom_title how can I show this?